# Let $a$ be an element of order $d$ in a finite abelian group. Show that if $m$ is any number with $a^m = e$, then $d$ divides $m.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $a$ be an element of order $d$ in a finite abelian group. Show (ii) of proposition 1, that if $m$ is any number with $a^m = e$, then $d$ divides $m$.

(ii) of proposition 1:
If $d$ is the order of $a$, and $m$ is any number with $a^m = e$, then $d$ divides $m.$

my answer, but not sure if this if right.

Suppose $a^e = 1$.  Let $d$ be the order of $a$.  Divide $e$ by $d$:  $e = dq + r.$  Then $a^e = (a^d)^q*a^r$.  So $1 = a^r$.  Since $0 \le r < d$, by minimality of $d$, we must have $r = 0$,  so $d$ divides $e.$

Comment: Yes, that is perfect.

Comment: It will work, but there is a significant systematic typo, you want $m$ not $e$. So divide $m$ by $d$, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. However, be careful in not confusing the $e$'s.